# Python: TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Tags: python, variables

This is my code:

```
print("Hello, what's your name?")
myName = sys.stdin.readline()
Join = input("Would you like to play a game, yes or no?").lower()
if Join.startswith('y'):
    print("Fine, you can play.")
else:
    print("Ok, goodbye.")
    sys.exit()
Color = input("So, first question. What's your favorite colour,
or do you have none?").lower()
if Color.startswith("n"):
    Thanks = input("Didn't expect much from you, good job", myName, 
" Say thanks, I complimented you!").lower()
else:
    print("Having a favorite colour is the wrong answer, try again.")
    sys.exit()
if Thanks.lower() == 'thanks':
    print("NEVER SAY THANKS!")
    sys.exit()
else:
    Continue = input("Well done, you didn't say THANKS. 
    Do you wish to  continue, yes or no?").lower()
if Continue.startswith('y'):
    print("Sure let's continue then.")
else:
    print("Too bad, you HAVE to continue!")
    sys.exit()
```

I'm new to programming, and I'm just making a "joke" code to practice. But I keep getting an error at this line:

```
Thanks = input("Didn't expect much from you, good job", myName, " Say thanks, I complimented you!").lower()
```

The error is:

> TypeError: input expected at most 1 arguments, got 3

Comment: You can join (concatenate) strings with `+`. The comma syntax is only for the `print` function, which will automatically join for you.

Answer (score 1):

Input takes a single argument, you are providing 3.

To concatenate strings, you can use `+` rather than `,`

`Thanks = input("Didn't expect much from you, good job "+ myName + 
+" Say thanks, I complimented you!").lower()`

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead:

```
Thanks = input("Didn't expect much from you, good job {} Say thanks, I complimented you!".format(myName))
```

Because of the ",", it gets it as parameters and doesn't concatenate the strings

Comment: Though this is probably the ideal solution, it'd probably be helpful to explain to the OP what this does, since they are clearly a beginner.